# Can't set color parameter in addCircleMarkers

Tags: r, leaflet

I can't get the leaflet `addCircleMarkers` function to apply data-mapped colors to the markers.

Nb. I generated `fn.palette` using `colorRampPalette`. It works fine, producing hex codes for colors from green > yellow > red when mapping the data vector `x`. The output vector `colours` looks like ("#00FF00FF" "#FFD200FF" "#7FFF00FF" "#FFFF00FF" ...).

If I set `color` to my vector of hex codes:

```
map %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lon, lat, color = colours, radius = 2, weight = 0,
                     fill = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.5, opacity = 0.6)
```

it draws only black markers.

If I use the `leaflet::pal` function:

```
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = fn.palette, domain = x)
map %>% addCircleMarkers(lon, lat, color = pal(x), radius = radius, 
                         stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1)
```

it gives

> Warning message:
>   In seq.int(0, 1, length.out = n) :
>    first element used of 'length.out' argument

and draws only black markers.

Using `color = ~pal(x)` instead of `color = pal(x)` (as in the examples at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet) throws

> Error in UseMethod("metaData") : 
>    no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "NULL"

I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reproducible example of making a leaflet map in R with coloured circle markers.

```
library(leaflet)
library(viridisLite)

# get domain of numeric data
(domain <- range(quakes$depth))

# make palette
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = viridis(100), domain = domain)

# make map
leaflet(quakes) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal(depth))
```

### Some pointers:

1) When making the palette using `colorNumeric` (assuming you have numeric data you wish to map) ensure the `domain` argument is the possible values that can be mapped.

> For colorNumeric and colorBin, this can be a simple numeric range (e.g. c(0, 100))

Here I have first calculated the range of `quakes$depth`.

2) Do ensure you use the syntax `color = ~pal(depth)` in `addCircleMarkers`

3) Also ensure the argument to `~pal()` is the numeric variable in your data that you want your palette mapped to.

Comment: I see. `colorNumeric` needs the `palette` argument to be a vector of colors -- not a palette function generated by `colorRampPalette` (even though the documentation the documentation implies otherwise).